# How to revert to Windows 10 from Windows 11 after deleting windows.old folder?

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, restore, windows-11

I installed Windows 11 three months ago and didn't know `windows.old` would be very important, so I deleted it; however, I've decided to go back to Windows 10, but could not revert, with the only choice being to lose all my data *(which I don't want since there are many important files and my personalization settings will be deleted)*.

One drive can't store my hard drive in its cloud, so how do I get back to Windows 10 from Windows 11 without having to lose all my data?

Comment: This is one of many reasons why user data should be stored/moved to a partition other than `C:`. You could use the [USMT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-overview) to backup the user profile, settings, and user data, however the most efficient way to avoid this is the prior sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You could just copy all the files and folders you think are important to another `drive/USB`, create a Windows 10 installation media on a `USB`, and just install it.
Another way I can think of is to try to recover the deleted folder with forensic software like `testdisk`, `foremost`, etc. If the folder has been deleted long time ago, it is possible that the data on the disk may have already been overwritten, making it impossible to recover the `Windows.old` folder.

Answer (score 0):

> The only choice is losing all my data, though i don't want to, since there are many important files and all my personalization settings will be deleted.

Unfortunately, the default amount of time to rollback your system is 10 days, and the maximum amount of time is 60 days.  The maximum amount of time is only applicable if you change the rollback time before the 10 days.

Since it’s been more than 60 days, and Windows.old has already been purged from your system, it’s impossible to revert to a build lower than the build you have.

> The only choice is losing all my data, though i don't want to, since there are many important files and all my personalization settings will be deleted.

The only way to safe your data is to purchase additional adequate storage for your data and the perform a clean install of Windows 10 21H2.  This will mean you will perform a clean install.

There is absolutely no way to reinstall Windows 10 21H2 and keep your data since you are on a higher build.  Windows only allows you to upgrade your build.

Copying your NTUSER.DAT will accomplish absolutely nothing and would be a complete waste of time.

Comment: Knowing which license keys you have is important. In my personal experience, with nearly every product key being emailed to me, I don’t really worry about it. However, the question was how to rollback to Windows 10, not properly transition back to it.  Since there real isn’t a clean way, and the only way is to perform a clean Windows 10 install, I feel  copying applications settings is entirely up to the owner of the device.